# Read cookie from parent directory

Tags: php, http, cookies

In http://myDomain.com/sub_directory/index.php, I created a cookie as follows:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Hello!");
echo('<pre>'.print_r($_COOKIE,1).'</pre>');
```

How do I access that cookie in a parent directory (i.e. http://myDomain.com/index.php)? Note that I do not wish to change the way I am saving my cookie in the subdirectory.  Thank you

Comment: Browsers won't send the cookies no matter what the second server asks. It's the source that you have to change. if you can't change the source, I think an iframe based method would do the job.

Comment: @AyeshK.  Thanks.  I guess that makes sense.  Knowing the answer is good enough, and I don't need/want to go down the iframe path.  Feel free to answer the question "You can't" and I will select it.

Comment: @AyeshK  If you also wanted to expand on why browsers won't send the cookie, that would be nice.